# mod_rewrite -> rewrite rule replacing application context part in original url

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd, apache2

I have requirement where user will type url like `http://example.com/Welcome` in browser, but I need to send it to `http://myip.com/someapp/next.html`, so I wrote virtual host in httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://myip.com/someapp/next.html" [P]
     ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://myip.com/someapp/next.html"

</VirtualHost>
```

This is working partly. When user enter url `http://example.com/Welcome`it is being replaced with `http://example.com`. How can I keep complete url (`http://example.com/Welcome`)? would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**
Here is the access_log surrounding the call

```
184.180.123.46 - - [06/Dec/2017:21:10:41 +0000] "GET /myip.com/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6697 "http://example.com/Welcome" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
184.180.123.46 - - [06/Dec/2017:21:10:51 +0000] "POST /myip/somepage HTTP/1.1" 200 7 "http://example.com/Welcome" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
184.180.123.46 - - [06/Dec/2017:21:10:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3391 "http://example.com/Welcome" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
184.180.123.46 - - [06/Dec/2017:21:11:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3391 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: "being replaced with" - Presumably you are seeing a 3xx redirect? Or not? There would seem to be _something else_ doing that.

Comment: @MrWhite no, I am not seeing any 302 in access_log, all I see 200.

Comment: The access log you have posted doesn't include the request for `/Welcome`? Also, the request for `/` shows `/Welcome` as a _Referer_, so that could suggest a meta or JavaScript "redirect" in the web application itself.